# Is there an inconsistency with the DNS specification?

Tags: dns

I'm a bit confused about something in the **[DNS Specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)**.

So, I think I understand the spec pretty well, but I'm confused about the fact that a single DNS response datagram includes a SINGLE message header, but apparently can be an answer to MULTIPLE questions.

So for example, the ***DNS message header*** contains a lot of information and flags that indicate information about the response.  For example, the DNS message header includes a Response Code flag that indicates various error codes, such as the "Not Implemented" error code, which means that the questioner asked for a record type which the server doesn't support.

But the problem is that the [**DNS spec**](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) allows for multiple questions sent in one Datagram (I mean, what else would the `QDCOUNT` field be for?)  I've never actually seen a DNS client ask more than one question at a time, but apparently it's allowed.

So... say a client asks TWO questions - so that `QDCOUNT` is set to 2.  How then exactly does the DNS client know which answers refer to which question?  (There may be any number of answers.) Or for that matter, how does the DNS client know which questions the error codes in the header refer to?

**Example:**

Suppose the DNS client asks for an **`A`** (IPv4) record and also an **`AAAA`** (IPv6) record in a single query.  And let's say the server supports `A` records - but *doesn't* implement `AAAA` records.

What should the server do?  Return a response that includes only `A` record answers - or return a response that *doesn't* include ANY answers and sets the [**"Not Implemented"**](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSMessageHeaderandQuestionSectionFormat.htm) error code flag?

This doesn't seem clear from the spec.  Overall, the problem seems to be that even though the spec allows for multiple questions in a single query datagram, there doesn't seem to be any way to map specific questions to specific answers in the response datagram.  Is this a problem with the spec?  Or am I misinterpreting something here?  Perhaps this is why in practice no actual DNS resolver seems to submit more than one question per datagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a flaw in the early DNS specifications, yes. In practice, if you try sending requests with multiple questions to any authoritative name server software in current use, it will ignore all questions but the first or give you an error response (usually SERVFAIL or FORMERR, in my experience).

If you manage to find a server in the wild that does something else, I would very much like to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you describe is not well characterized as an inconsistency -- the spec does not conflict with itself -- rather, it is more of a hole.  I had a quick look and did not find any specification for how a server should respond to a request that contains multiple questions where one or more demands an error response.

I can think of several possible server behaviors, not necessarily distinguishable by a client, therefore the best approach for a client is probably to avoid the situation by not posing multiple questions in the same message.  The RFC asserts that that is the normal case, and I think it's right, even where the client wants multiple kinds of information associated with the same name.

I am uncertain how any particular name server handles the situation, but were I implementing one myself then I would strongly consider refusing all such multi-question messages with error code 5 (request refused because of server policy).